# Facebook - migrating fb:comments from href to xid?

Tags: facebook, api, comments, facebook-fql

I'm working on a site that is currently using the fb:comments plugin, and unfortunately I started the site with the 'new' edition that uses href instead of xid as the identifier. I need to move back to xid's in order to retrieve comment count (unless you know of another way besides fb:comment-count), and I don't know how to do so without losing all of the existing comments for that box.

This is kind of a big deal because some of the fb:comments have hundreds of entries already, so I'm sure they won't be too happy if I wiped it out.

So, is there a way to transition existing comments from an fb:comments using href to one using xid? If not, is there a way to retrieve comment count of an href-style fb:comments plugin?

Thanks as always!